# Set display:flex as the default for a display:none element in css?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, flexbox

Is there any way to set an element to `display:none` to initially hide it and also specify that, when the element is shown later by JavaScript, it be shown as `display:flex`?

**Example CSS**:

```
#Container{
   display:flex;
   display:none;    
}
```

**Example jQuery**:

```
$('#Container').show();
```

Desired behavior: This shows the element as `display:flex` *without* hard-coding a value of `flex` in JavaScript.

*Note: I am well aware that I can simply set the element to `display:flex` with jQuery's CSS method. However, the goal is to separate functionality from presentation, and whether an element is flex or block or inline is not the business of the JavaScript code. JavaScript's job is simply to show or hide it, not to change how the page is presented.*

*I'm also aware that I could wrap the `display:flex` element in a `display:none` element and show and hide the outer wrapper. But I'm curious to know if there is a clever way of achieving this without adding extra divs around every pane.*

Comment: Could you use another class to hide the elements? Then just remove the hiding class with JS and you end up with the flex from original css?

Comment: as sami says, use use `addClass()`/`removeClass()` which is also a good practice

Comment: That's what I'm doing now, but I was hoping since it's 2017 and we have flex boxes and web sockets that we might have some clever way to set a default display type for an element that doesn't get clobbered by hiding it.

Comment: @Nick What you want is [`box-supress`](https://www.w3.org/TR/2015/WD-css-display-3-20151015/#box-suppress). The proposal has been deferred, so we will need to wait some years.

Comment: @Oriol - Yes, that's the kind of answer I was looking for. It only took them 20 years to get vertical alignment working so I'm optimistic that they'll sort this one out... in time.

Comment: @Nick We "only" need to wait for that property to be reintroduced in the next module level, then for the CSS WG to rename it to something they like, then for browsers to implement it, then for stabilization, then for jQuery to make `show` and `hide` use it. Maybe it will also take 20 years.

Answer (score 5):

The best way to do it would be to just add a class to the element instead of `show()`. Then this class has the property of `display: flex`:

```js
$('div').addClass('flex');
```

```css
div {
  display: none;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}
div.flex {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
```

But if you want to use `show()` you can do something like this:

```js
$('div').show();
```

```css
div {
  display: none;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}
div[style*="display: block"] {
  display: flex !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
```

When using `show()` on the div, it sets the div to `display block`, so by using `div[style*=display: block]` it selects the div whose `style`-attribute contains `display: block`. Then we override it by adding `display: flex !important`.

Comment: Can you explain how the `div[style*="block"]` syntax works? Or is there any documentation on it? I assume it means "take anything that has a style of "block" and apply the rules to it", but what is the `*` for? Why not `div[display="block"]`?

Comment: Because `div[style="block"` only selects the div which have style=block. With the `*=` it selects the div which style contains "block"

Comment: If you want to do it without the `*` you have to write the full style: `div[style="display: block;"]`.

Comment: I think you're on to something here. By combining the attribute selector with a class name, and since Jquery is consistent about adding an in-line element style, this might just work until `box-suppress` comes out.

Answer (score 3):

One of the most flexible options is to create some utility classes:

```
.hidden{ display: none; }
.flex{ display: flex; }
```

Then:

```
$('#Container').addClass('flex');
```

Comment: In order to hide elements by default though, you have to add the `hidden` class to every single one of them in the HTML. It's much cleaner to do `.panes{display:none;}` than to add a new `hidden` class to every pane

Comment: You can do whatever your heart desires, this was just an example.

Comment: I would extend the `.hidden` utility class to be `display: none!improtant;`, then you can leave the `.flex` class on the element all the time and just have javascript add and remove `.hidden`.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend use of `!important`.